Rigify generating IK targets in wrong location
When I generate my rig, the elbow and knee IK targets are in the wrong location. This means as soon as I switch the rig to use the IK Pole's, it adds twist to the elbow/knee. They joints are bending in the correct direction, but they are getting this extra twist. I can edit the rig in edit mode and align the target with the joint, but if I re-generate the rig it is wrong agian.


The Meta rig has all the bones aligned properly:

The arm and leg bones are using a specified Rotation Axis, not automatic. But the problem happens with automatic too. There are no unapplied Object transforms.

How does rigify determine where the IK targets are placed, and how do I fix this?

Take a look in manual:

While placing the arm bones try to start having a straight line that
goes from the shoulder to the hand in both front and top view. After
this is done just add a slight bend to the elbow. This can be easily
done by going in the top view, entering armature Edit Mode and sliding
the bone junction between forearm and upper_arm slightly toward the
world’s Y axis.


From your screenshots, I see, that you have this "slight bend" in wrong direction

Ah i have the bend correct going backwards on Y, but there was a slight bend on X too and that was messing it up.
